# Python Sum Scores from CSV

Tags: python

I am creating a program that is supposed to read data in a file called "Diving.csv". Each line in the file has a  set of scores for each contestant in a diving competition. The program needs to find and display the highest and lowest score for each contestant. It should then find the final score for each contestant by finding the sum of each diver's score (except for the largest and smallest) and then multiplying the sum by 0.6. This should then be displayed after each max and min score. Each contestant has 11 scores.

I believe the problem is in either the read file procedure or the function to calculate the scores?  Any help much appreciated.

Here is an example of the csv:
[image: Driving csv]

```
#Procedure to Read File
def ReadFile():

class Diving():
 score1 = 0.0
 score2 = 0.0
 score3 = 0.0
 score4 = 0.0
 score5 = 0.0
 score6 = 0.0
 score7 = 0.0
 score8 = 0.0
 score9 = 0.0
 score10 = 0.0
 score11 = 0.0

 diving = [Diving() for x in range(10)]

 counter = 0

with open("Diving.csv","r") as readfile:
  line = readfile.readline().rstrip("\n")

while line:
  items = line.split(",")
  diving[counter].score1 = float(items[0])
  diving[counter].score2 = float(items[1])
  diving[counter].score3 = float(items[2])
  diving[counter].score4 = float(items[3])
  diving[counter].score5 = float(items[4])
  diving[counter].score6 = float(items[5])
  diving[counter].score7 = float(items[6])
  diving[counter].score8 = float(items[7])
  diving[counter].score9 = float(items[8])
  diving[counter].score10 = float(items[9])
  diving[counter].score11 = float(items[10])

  line = readfile.readline().rstrip("\n")
  counter += 1

input("File read... Press any key to continue")

return diving

#Procedure to Calculate Scores
def CalcScores(diving):

score = [0]*10

for i in range(10):
  maxmin= [float(diving[i].score1),float(diving[i].score2),float(diving[i].score3),float(diving[i].score4),float(diving[i].score5),float(diving[i].score6),float(diving[i].score7),float(diving[i].score8),float(diving[i].score9),float(diving[i].score10),float(diving[i].score11)]

min = maxmin[0]
max = maxmin[0]

for loop in range(11):
  if float(maxmin[loop]) < min:
    min = maxmin[loop]
  if float(maxmin[loop]) > max:
    max = maxmin[loop]

  print("min =",min,"max =",max)

  score[i] = ((diving[i].score1+diving[i].score2+diving[i].score3+diving[i].score4+diving[i].score5+diving[i].score6+diving[i].score7+diving[i].score8+diving[i].score9+diving[i].score10+diving[i].score11)-min-max)*0.6

return score

#Procedure to Display Scores
def DisplayScore(score):
  for counter in range(len(score)):
   print("Score",counter+1,"=",round(score[counter],2))

#Main Program

diving = ReadFile()

score = CalcScores(diving)

DisplayScore(score)
```

Comment: So instead of class Diving():
 score1 = 0.0
 score2 = 0.0
 score3 = 0.0
 score4 = 0.0
 score5 = 0.0
 score6 = 0.0
 score7 = 0.0
 score8 = 0.0
 score9 = 0.0
 score10 = 0.0
 score11 = 0.0   use: def __init__(self):
    self.diving = []

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was not creating an Array of Diving Scores.

So instead of `diving=[Diving() for x in range(10)]`

It should have been `divingArray=[Diving() for x in range(10)]`

Having set up the array, I could then correctly assign the scores for each item in the loop:

```
divingArray[counter].score1=float(item[0])
```

and `return divingArray`

This was also the case for finding the min and max of each score:

```
score[i]=divingArray[i].score1 .... etc
```

Finally, to calculate the score, I just passed in divingArray as a paramater of my calcScores function:

```
score = calcScores(divingArray)
```